# WCF service for Sl3

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0

I have written a simple service that uploads & downloads XML files.  I want to implement it in a Silverlight 3 project, but on doing so I get following warnings:

**Warning   1   Custom tool warning: Endpoint 'BasicHttpBinding_IxmlLoad' at address 'http://tony-pc/xmlLoadService/Service.svc' is not compatible with Silverlight 3. Skipping...
**

**Warning   2   Custom tool warning: No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 3 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor.
**

Although I have the following endpoint config in my web.config file:

```
      <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHTTP" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
             closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
             openTimeout="00:03:00" 
             messageEncoding="Mtom" 
             maxBufferSize="100000" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="100000" 
             transferMode="StreamedResponse">
    </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="LoadXMLService.XMLOperations">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="basicHTTP" 
              contract="LoadXMLService.IxmlLoad" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

My service is hosted in IIS 7.0.

Can anyone help me as to what is wrong?

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big expert in Silverlight, but I'm pretty sure one of these two config entries is the culprit:

```
messageEncoding="Mtom"
```

Try: messageEncoding="Text" instead.

or

```
transferMode="StreamedResponse"
```

Try: transferMode="Buffered" instead.

Can you try with other values, just to see if that was the trouble maker?

Marc

Comment: Cool, but without these, will I still be able to up & download files via the service?

Comment: Sure - up to the MaxReceivedMessageSize parameter defined in your binding.