# Confused -> Silverlight 4 not allowing me to consume a WCF service using BasicHttpBinding?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

OK I am totally confused and hopefully I am missing something here totally obvious. I am consuming a WCF service of mine (which is ***stable and working*** in ASP.NET) hosted in a Windows Service which uses a 'BasicHttpBinding' configuration. When I try to consume it from a Silverlight 4 application I get the following error in VS.NET:

*"Custom tool warning: Endpoint '**BasicHttpBinding**_IMyService' at address 'https://mywcfservice:8000/WCFServices/MyService' **is not compatible with Silverlight 4**. Skipping... MyService\Reference.svcmap"*

What!? I know and have gone through the hoops to jump through for making a netTCPBinding which has issues get past the error above in SL4, but why in the world is BasicHttpBinding having any issue with SL4? I thought since like day 1 of SL2 BasicHttpBinding was the defacto and easiest binding for Silverlight to consume. Here is my WCF *server* configuration:

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpWindowsBinding"
              contract="IMyService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://mywcfservice:8000/WCFServices/MyService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpWindowsBinding"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="214748"
             messageEncoding="Mtom"
             transferMode="Streamed">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>     
</bindings>
```

What am I missing here? If anyone can help me or guide what might be incoorect please let me know. Thanks!

**Edit:** I *think* I might be on the trail - this service uses a 'Message Contract' as a parameter in a method and I wonder if this is causing any issues. However from this MSDN article: *"Message contracts are supported in Silverlight 4"* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571(v=vs.95).aspx so I am still not 100% sure. I check 'Always generate message contracts' when consuming but it made no difference.

Comment: Silverlight and WCF: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few **special** attributes/values you use in your configuration file:

*The BasicHttpWindowsBinding has transferMode and messageEncoding set to non default values.*

According to [WCF service for Sl3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548190/wcf-service-for-sl3), which registered similar problems, you should do the following:

> messageEncoding="Mtom"
>
> Try: messageEncoding="Text" instead.
>
> or transferMode="StreamedResponse"
>
> Try: transferMode="Buffered" instead.

If you try these steps, you will probably get a running situation and can build in specifics from that point on, making sure it keeps working for the SL-WCF connection.

Comment: Uhhh... #1 is not true at all. You absolutely can host a service using https with the BasicHttpBinding. I have been using this service for years and consuming in ASP.NET, WPF, and WinForms. Here is a MSDN blog documenting the following: *"The choices you have with BasicHttp are no security, **HTTPS security**, SOAP security, and HTTPS security with SOAP credentials."* http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/06/01/612672.aspx This also makes your #2 and #3 incorrect above.

Comment: I changed the answer, because you are right. Learned something tonight :-) But in point 2 were other items that could be of interest and I found and included a reference to problems with these settings in combination with SL. Would you be able to tryout to see if these cause the problem?

Comment: Thanks for updating and I will give a try and post back. However, please read my 'Edit' at the bottom of my OP. I think the problem is with me using a 'Message Contract'. SL I believe does not understand SOAP message headers and I think this may be causing the issue.

Comment: The settings I had *indeed* where not compatible with SL4, specifically the 'Streamed' value. Switching it fixed the issue, but not the overall problem, because now I am trying to figure out how to chunk files to the server to mimic what I was doing with streaming previously. Thanks for the help.